# ARIA tab role that isn't immediate child of tablist

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

Due to implementation restrictions, I'm not allowed to  add `role="tab` to the immediate children of the parent `role="tablist"` like in the following example:

```
<div role="tablist">
  <div class="this-wrapper-must-be-here-and-I-cannot-add-dynamic-content">
    <button role="tab" aria-setsize="2" aria-posinset="1">Tab 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="this-wrapper-must-be-here-and-I-cannot-add-dynamic-content">
    <button role="tab" aria-setsize="2" aria-posinset="2">Tab 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Voice Over speaks always "tab 1 of 1", because it can't refer to the far away parent with `tablist`. Is there a way to treat the `button` tag as immediate children of `tablist`?

Comment: Why have you got `aria-setsize` and `aria-posinset`? Those are designed for `listitem`s or `treeitem`s. It is quite possible that is what is breaking your Tabs as they are confusing the screen reader. `role="tab"` does not have to be a direct descendant and can sit within a container if needed. Also have you got valid `role="tabpanel"`s associated with `aria-controls` on the tab or `aria-labelledby` on the panel itself? That may also help.

Comment: Did any of the above work or do you need more help with this still?

Comment: thank you @GrahamRitchie, I did not need to use posinset as you mentioned, the tabs are working well with their parent tablist and the screenreader announces "one of two" as expected

Comment: Super, glad you got it sorted!